# What does specific icon mean in Visual Studio/TFS 2010?

Tags: icons

A few days ago a new icon (like a 3D locker with a red dot on top) appeared on some of my files in Source Control Explorer. I don't recall the actions I did before and now I am wondering what is the meaning of this symbol.
Unfortunately I cannot post images, so you can find it [here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/8y4woi.jpg).

Comment: When ou see your solution in windows explorer what do you get?

Comment: I see the same icons (as pictured in TFS) in windows explorer also.

Comment: It seems that the icon is only for solution files and appears in all the folders where such files exist. Still I don't remember them in this way before (let's say a week ago) and I didn't install anything meanwhile.

Comment: I think it's not a Visual studio or a tfs icon, it's just windows that associated your solution files to another application and it displays it like that. You can find that associated programme By doing as follow :
Windows => Default Programm => Associate a file type ...=> in the list find .sln extension if you cant try to find this icon.
Regards

Comment: Great! you are right Bouam. For some reason (which I don't know), the default program for .sln has been changed. I've switched back to VS and everything is fine. Such a relief that was only this and not another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a Visual studio or a tfs icon, it's just windows that associated your solution files to another application and it displays it like that. You can find that associated programme By doing as follow : Windows => Default Programm => Associate a file type ...=> in the list find .sln extension if you cant try to find this icon. Regards